# accessibility service permission lost after killing app in android 8.0

Tags: android

Hi i have created accessibility service permission  using below code .

```
 public static boolean isAccessibilitySettingsOn(Context mContext) {
        int accessibilityEnabled = 0;
        final String service = mContext.getPackageName() + "/" + YouTubeFilterService.class.getCanonicalName();
        try {
            accessibilityEnabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(
                    mContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                    android.provider.Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED);
            Log.v(TAG, "accessibilityEnabled = " + accessibilityEnabled);
        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: "
                    + e.getMessage());
        }
        TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter mStringColonSplitter = new TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter(':');

        if (accessibilityEnabled == 1) {
            Log.v(TAG, "***ACCESSIBILITY IS ENABLED*** -----------------");
            String settingValue = Settings.Secure.getString(
                    mContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES);
            if (settingValue != null) {
                mStringColonSplitter.setString(settingValue);
                while (mStringColonSplitter.hasNext()) {
                    String accessibilityService = mStringColonSplitter.next();

                    Log.v(TAG, "-------------- > accessibilityService :: " + accessibilityService + " " + service);
                    if (accessibilityService.equalsIgnoreCase(service)) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "We've found the correct setting - accessibility is switched on!");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "***ACCESSIBILITY IS DISABLED***");
        }

        return false;
    }
```

This is working properly in android 8 above when i give permission its save permission status but in android 8.0 and android 8.1 when i give permission to ON and again if i kill and launch then its asking again permission while it should be save permission status please help me what i am doing wrong .

Comment: I cannot find any LOC that actually sets accessibility service value here. Are you really setting a value?

Comment: @NightFury  using above code i am setting value can you please check